# Loosing Root Access On USB Disconnect

Tags: boot, usb, root

When I plug in my usb and then unplug it I unexpectedly loose root access on my computer. Furthermore, when I reboot my computer it prompts me with the message saying

```
Errors were found when reading the disk. Press F to try to fix.
```

and when I press <kbd>F</kbd> it says `Cannot locate directory /tmp` and eventually boots up fine.

Along with this problem still occurring, other small things have happened too but I need to verify this is the direct cause of them before I blab about those problems too.

Comment: I believe the problem was a hardware issue, possibly caused by overheating/3 years of constant use. Most likely not a bug with Ubuntu.